# derive dataframe column in django views with pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

I'm retrieving some data from a database

But before sending them to frontend, I'd like to do some basics data manipulations.

```
def mypage(request)
   #database request here
   # [...]
   #now I'm pushing it into a dataframe - this works!
   myresults=pd.DataFrame(mydata.data())

   #now I'm selecting a subset of the retrieved data - this works!
   myresults=myresults[["VAR1","VAR2","VAR3"]]

   #now I'm trying to derive VAR4, setting it equal to VAR3
   #the basic pandas syntax seems correct, but in Django for some reasons it fails
   myresults["VAR4"]=myresults["VAR3"]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried to achieve the same using numpy - but failed again.

Thanks.

---

edit:

removing the failing statement above and rendering myresults with print(myresults) I get the expected results:

```
     VAR1     VAR2      VAR3
0    VAR1ROW0 VAR2ROW0  VAR3ROW0
1    VAR1ROW1 VAR2ROW1  VAR3ROW1
```

Comment: post error that you get

Comment: no errors in the shell, just a Server Error (500) in the page, telling me that something is wrong in the code. The page is getting loaded properly removing the last statement in the code sample above.

Comment: try to render results from `myresults` without last line of code, and post them.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi done with an edit in the original post. the content is as expected.

Comment: I have tested on my template and all is working fine, try to check log file to find the problem. I think something is throwing error and that why the page is not